# Best way to do extraction of data from a REST API using the AWS ecosystem using Python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, rest, aws-lambda, aws-glue

I'm looking for advice on how to properly go about extracting data from a REST Api using the AWS ecosystem. I'm currently using Python and chron to accomplish this but want to implement in AWS the "accepted way". I have researched Glue and Lambda. It looks pretty easy using Lambda. Using Glue looks to need 3rd party software like [Progress DataDirect Autonomous REST Connector for JDBC](https://www.progress.com/download/thank-you?interface=jdbc&ds=autonomous-rest-api&os=win) to smoothly accomplish this but I would prefer to only use native AWS tools. What is the best way to go about doing this? Thanks in advance, Ed.